# I would like to know is there a 64 bit version of advapi32.dll?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have application on windows server 2008 which gets request for connection via web. The connection is made through registry key. I get this error "The description for Event ID 9300 from source CUSTOMPROJECT Security 3335 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

ActiveX component can't create object

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table"

I would like to know is there a 64 bit version of advapi32.dll ?

Comment: If you are still using Stack Overflow, please accept the answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

On a **32-bit computer**, all 32-bit programs store their files in C:\Program Files, and the system-wide library location is **C:\System32**.

On a **64-bit computer**, 64-bit programs store their files in C:\Program Files, and the system-wide **C:\Windows\System32** folder contains 64-bit libraries. 32-bit programs store their files in C:\Program Files (x86), and the system-wide folder is **C:\Windows\SysWOW64**.

The “WOW64” part of the name here refers to Microsoft’s “Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit” software, which is a part of the operating system. This allows Windows to run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit version of Windows. WoW64 redirects file access to ensure programs will work properly.

Here is a good [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/) explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for [advapi**64**.dll](https://www.google.com/search?q=advapi64.dll) returns a fair number of results.

I also found this link:

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/netfx64bit/thread/410374d5-139a-47f9-9d5b-3851247f4024

Which indicates you should look for the 64-bit version of the file here:

> %WinDir%\System32

Comment: This answer links to a correct one on MSDN, but itself is incorrect. Anything under %windir%\SysWOW64 is purely 32-bit, so don't be fooled by the folder name. WOW64 means Windows 32 bit on Windows 64 bit.